# Preventing data persistence in pickle

Tags: python, pickle, torchtext

I am trying to read in a pickle file containing a `torchtext.data.field.Field` object, however my current repo is using a more updated version of torchtext and thus the data type is `torchtext.legacy.data.field`, the code throws an error immediately when I run `pickle.load()`, is there any workarounds for this problem?